# Blank screen on autostarting GUI application in Openbox WM Arch Li

Tags: archlinux, xorg

I have installed Xserver with Openbox window manager in my Raspberry pi with Arch Linux. I have done setup to auto start Xserver with Openbox WM and then starting my python-tkinter GUI application from "/etc/xdg/openbox/autostart". I have followed Arch Linux documentation for above configuration.

My application auto starts successfully. As I have to do some extra configuration,I have closed my application using 'Alt+F4'. Now I am seeing a blank screen and not able to open a terminal to continue with the configuration.

When I right click on the screen, I have a option to open xterm but it does not work. I have gone through Arch Linux documentation for any key board shortcuts or other techniques but, I did not find any.

Please suggest a way to have a terminal after closing my application so that I can install extra packages I need. I do not want to redo the complete procedure with all dependencies again. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have just found a way to log-in into system through another session using "Alt+Ctrl+F6/F7". I still want to find out weather it is possible to open a terminal window in GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending quite some time, I found the problem is that xterm is not getting started. It turns out that, when I am experimenting by installing and removing other packages, I had removed some of dependencies of xterm.

I am able to explore this by logging in to another session using "Alt+Ctrl+F6/F7".

Finally fixed my problem by installing xterm again properly. Sorry for troubling everyone with a simple mistake of mine.

Comment: I did it as you asked @AwesomeUser